# Does thunderous throw permit iterative attacks with two-handed thrown weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, ranged-attack, tome-of-battle, throwing-things

The *Player's Handbook* on [Thrown Weapons](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#thrown-weapons) says, "Throwing a light or one-handed weapon is a standard action, while throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action" (113). The prestige class bloodstorm blade grants at level 2 the extraordinary ability thunderous throw that, in part, says

> As a swift action, you can choose to treat your ranged attack rolls with thrown weapons as melee attacks for the rest of your turn. You use your melee attack bonus, including Strength bonus, feats, and so forth, to determine your attack bonus for each attack as normal, but you apply the standard modifiers for range penalties. Attacking into melee, through cover, and so forth incurs the standard penalties. (*Tome of Battle* 101)

There seems to be just enough ambiguity in the thunderous throw description to disallow iterative attacks when a creature throws a two-handed weapon. I mean, it says *treat your attack rolls* [n.b.] *with thrown weapons as melee attacks* rather than saying *treat your attacks with thrown weapons as melee attacks*, for instance. However, not being well-versed in the intricacies of building or playing thrown-weapon-focused characters, I'm unsure how this has all shaken out in the decade or so since *Tome of Battle* was published.

Can a creature that possesses the extraordinary ability thunderous throw and the feat [Quick Draw](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#quick-draw) (*PH* 98) or some other means to speedily draw forth two-handed weapons make iterative attacks with its two-handed thrown weapons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Thunderous throw most likely doesn't matter.

First of all, the passage from Player's Handbook you quoted refers to throwing something that isn't designed to be thrown (doesn't have range in it's statistics).

So with something improvised thunderous throw won't help because it probably lists all purposes for which it makes your ranged attack to be treated like melee one (you probably can't use Combat Expertise as you can Power Attack for example). And for something which is an actual thrown weapon you already attack in place of a ranged attack not as a standard or a full-round action and don't need any enhancers.

Comment: You're correct that the *RC* does, in fact, clarify by saying, "Throwing… a two-handed weapon that isn’t designed to be thrown is a full-round action" (150). (A statement with which I was until now totally unaware, having *always* played that a 2-handed thrown weapon takes a full-round action to hurl! Every day this game's vastness continues to impress—and depress—me.) That combined with the feat Throw Anything that a bloodstorm blade gets for free should eliminate any ambiguity about thunderous throw. Cool. Thanks.