# Hammer of Moradin - Hammer return and additional attacks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, throwing-things

What kind of magic enchantment would make my war hammer return immediately before my next attack so I can make four ranged attacks?

Few details:

I would like to have my character (22 lvl multi class character) to use all of his melee attacks to throw war hammer. One of the classes i multiclass is Hammer of Moradin.

At second level Hammer of Moradin prestige class receive supernatural ability to make any war hammer he throws gain returning special ability. Since returning special ability grants returning of thrown weapon just before starting next round, I can make either one ranged attack per round or four melee attacks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120065/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/126010/8610). Thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really, really want is the bloodstorm blade prestige class from *Tome of Battle*. That class offers this class feature at 4th level:

> **Lightning Ricochet (Ex):** From 4th level on, you can throw your weapon at a nearby foe and command it to immediately bounce back to your grasp. Any time you make a ranged attack with a thrown weapon on your turn, the weapon immediately returns to you, and you can catch it as a free action. This ability allows you to make a full attack entirely with thrown weapon attacks, or a mix of thrown and melee attacks.

There is no way to get this feature in item or feat form. If you can back-port Pathfinder material, the [*blinkback belt*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-blink-back/) does it, and is an excellent choice, but that is not 3.5e material.

Also worth noting, the same prestige class offers thunderous throw at 2nd, which allows you to treat your thrown-weapon attacks as melee (allowing you to use Strength, Power Attack, etc. etc.), which can be really potent. The rest of the class is pretty much meh, but four levels is all-but-mandatory for a thrown weapon character, particularly one who wishes to use a warhammer rather than shuriken or similar.

These benefits also synergize really nicely with hammer of Moradin: since your throws are treated as melee attacks, powerful grip applies to these attacks, and then you can use power throw to attack a whole line of people, gaining pretty large damage bonuses, several times a round. That’s pretty nice, and totally makes up for the fact that hammer return is redundant with lightning ricochet.

But despite that, please note that it is all-but-impossible to keep an epic-level game functional, and martial characters in particular have almost-zero ability to retain relevance in the face of competent use of epic magic, [particularly Epic Spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22268/4563). In fact, D&D 3.5e has so much difficulty with increasing level that many games actually stop at *6th* ([see E6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97252/4563)), because even as early as 7th these problems get to be pretty severe. This character may struggle massively to contribute much in a campaign so high-level. Frankly, the campaign as a whole may struggle mightily just to remain coherent.

Comment: Thanks KRayan. Lightning Ricochet is exactly what i'm looking for but...

Comment: I already play this character for years now and i don't have prerequisites for Bloodstorm Blade. Yes epic level spellcasters are dangerous but i managed to survive by having very competent epic level spellcaster on my side. Our campaigns are more hack and slash with occasional need for insightfull spellcasting so this keeps me relevant in game.

Comment: Blink back belt would be excelent solution but i alredy have belt of giant strenght +5 so this would be downgrade on my opinion.

Comment: @tbalaz You can combine magic items; per _Magic Item Compendium_, it doesn’t even cost extra for a basic feature like _belt of giant strength_. So you can have the benefits of a _blinkback belt_ added to your _belt of giant strength_ for the same cost as a new _blinkback belt_. (While you’re at it, you might like to also consider adding a _belt of battle_ to it, but having both _blinkback_ and _of battle_ makes one cost 50% more.)

Comment: Thanks. I just confirmed with my DM that I can request Blinkback belt "of battle" from some Clerics owning me a favor. This is so cute. Now those power throws will become really fun.